# ActionLink helper in MVC navigates after second click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a home page with different links inside, once I click in one of them, stay on the same page, the second click performs the redirect, why?

My **HomeController** looks like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Razor View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Reports Index</h2>

<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manual Rental Reconciliation Audit", "Index", "ManRecReport")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manual Rental By Status", "Index", "RecStatusReport")</li>
</ul>
```

Here are the Headers after the first click

[image]

The generated html with the first click and without it is the same

```
<h2>Reports Index</h2>

<ul>

    <li><a href="/ManRecReport">Manual Rental Reconciliation Audit</a></li>
    <li><a href="/RecStatusReport">Manual Rental By Status</a></li>
</ul>
```

The controller method inside **ManRecReportController** is hit just after the second click. What is happening here?

Comment: What does your `ManRecReportController` Index action look like?

Comment: Also please make sure to actually provide [MCVE]  - since redirect location is "auth.aspx" there is something related to auth not shown in the code provided.

Answer (score 2):

Status code 302 is a redirect, and it's pointing to auth.aspx, which is odd considering this is an MVC application.  My guess is you have some sort of redirect to an authentication page if the user has not logged in yet, and that page is then redirecting a second time back to Index.  That's why the link works the second time but not the first.

We would need to know more about how you are doing auth to answer.